# How to plot 95 percentile and 5 percentile on ggplot2 plot with already calculated values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentile

I have [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14322966/long-without-NFP-and-FP.csv) dataset and use this R code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RGraphics)
library(gridExtra)

long <- read.csv("long.csv")
ix <- 1:14

ggp2 <- ggplot(long, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = numbers), vjust=-0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3, angle = 0) +
    scale_x_continuous("Nodes", breaks = ix) +
    scale_y_continuous("Throughput (Mbps)", limits = c(0,1060)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Legend",
                        labels=c("Inside Firewall (Dest)",
                                 "Inside Firewall (Source)",
                                 "Outside Firewall (Dest)",
                                 "Outside Firewall (Source)")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="right") +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=14, face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold")) +
    facet_grid(type ~ .) +
plot(ggp2)
```

to get the following result:
[image]

Now I need to add the 95 percentile and 5 percentile to the plot. The numbers are calculated in [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14322966/long-with-NFP-and-FP.csv) dataset (NFPnumbers (95 percentile) and FPnumbers (5 percentile) columns).

It seems `boxplot()` may work here but I am not sure how to use it with ggplot.
`stat_quantile(quantiles = c(0.05,0.95))` could work as well, but the function calculates the numbers itself. Can I use my numbers here?

I also tried:

```
geom_line(aes(x = id, y = long$FPnumbers)) +
geom_line(aes(x = id, y = long$NFPnumbers))
```

but the result did not look good enough.

`geom_boxplot()` did not work as well:

```
geom_boxplot(aes(x = id, y = long$FPnumbers)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x = id, y = long$NFPnumbers))
```

Comment: Side issue: What additional information do colors bring to the plot?

Comment: When I remove `facet_grid(type ~ .)` from `ggplot`, colors help to link the bars with the "Legend".

Comment: Another option would be to change factor levels and legend would become obsolete. Just thinking out loud...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several suitable geoms for that, `geom_errorbar` is one of them:

```
ggp2 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = NFPnumbers, ymin = FPnumbers), alpha = 0.5, width = 0.5)
```

[image]

I don't know if there's a way to get rid of the central line though.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to set the parameters for a boxplot, you also need `ymin` and `ymax` values. As they are not in the dataset, I calculated them.

```
ggplot(long, aes(x = factor(id), y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower = FPnumbers, middle = value, upper = NFPnumbers, ymin = FPnumbers*0.5, ymax = NFPnumbers*1.2, fill = type), stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Nodes") +
  ylab("Throughput (Mbps)") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Legend",
                      labels=c("Inside Firewall (Dest)", "Inside Firewall (Source)",
                               "Outside Firewall (Dest)", "Outside Firewall (Source)")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="right",
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=14, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold")) +
  facet_grid(type ~ .)
```

The result:

[image]

---

In the dataset you provided, you gave the `value`, `FPnumbers` & `NFPnumbers` variables. As `FPnumbers` & `NFPnumbers` represent the 5 and 95 percentiles, I suppose that the mean is represented by `value`. For this solution to work, you'll need `min` and `max` values for each "Node". I guess you have them somewhere in your raw data.

However, as they are not provided in the dataset, I made them up by calculating them based on `FPnumbers` & `NFPnumbers`. The multiplication factors of `0.5` and `1.2` are arbitrary. It is just a way of creating fictitious `min` and `max` values.

Comment: Why did the bars move up? Is it because the colorful parts of bars represent values between 5 percentile and 95 percentile? What about the horizontal lines? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the colorful part of bars represent the values between the 5 and 95 percentiles. The horizontal lines inside the boxes are the middle values (i.e. the values from the variable `value`).

Comment: Why did you do `..., FPnumbers*0.5, ymax = NFPnumbers*1.2, ...`? Why 0.5 and 1.2?

Comment: see the explanation I added to the end of my answer